# How to start a thread on another core without setting processor affinity to a specific core?

Tags: c++, linux, stl, multiprocessing

How to start `std::thread` on another core without explicitly setting processor affinity to a specific core?

I am aware that the thread can be assigned to a specific core however is there a way to tell the scheduler to start the process on another core and let the scheduler decide which core is best to run the process on?

Comment: The title says **how to start a thread on another core**. The body of the question says **to start the process on another core**. Sorry if i misanderstood, could you be more precise?

Comment: @Neb thread = process

Comment: @Dave The whole point of threads is not to start another process.

Comment: @user0042 My understanding was that thread calls the linux kernel abi which forks the parent process and creates a child process? The problem is how to ensure that the new process starts on a different core (vs the same one)? I know the scheduler will most likely switch it however is there a way to tell the scheduler to run it on a different core from the start?

Comment: @Dave No. Creating threads doesn't work this way.

Comment: @user0042 What is incorrect about my understanding?

Comment: @Dave As mentioned, the whole point of threads is to avoid forking a child process.

Comment: @user0042 My bad, I was going off [cppreference.com documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) which stated that `Threads enable programs to execute across several processor cores.`. What should I be using instead of threads?

Comment: Thread != process. A process can have multiple threads. Multiple thread of a process share the same physical address space and the same files opened by the process they belong to. But, they are independent control flows of the process and so they do have their own register set.

Comment: @Dave Well, what is the issue you want to solve? If you have multiple processes the operating system usually schedules these to use all the available cores in a shared manner.

Comment: @user0042 I am working with a large array and I would like to process it in slices on multiple cores (a map-reduce type of job where the input is not mutated). Because it is a computationally expensive task I want to make sure that it runs on multiple cores,

Comment: @Dave So use threads to do this. The scheduler will use them in an optimized manner to parallelize your code execution. No need that you set core affinity.

Comment: @user0042 Is there a way to ensure (or encourage) the scheduler to place the tasks on different cores? Preferably without inspecting core utilizations/setting affinity manually.

Comment: @Dave You can enhance chances of scheduling off concurrent tasks using [`std::this_thread::yield()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) for example. But beyond that there's no way other than setting the processor affinity as you mentioned.

Comment: @user0042 Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you don't.

You have two choices:

1. You choose the processor core(s) the thread can run on, by setting its affinity.
2. You let the scheduler choose which core(s) the thread will run on.

Either you choose, or the scheduler chooses. Simple as that.

For what you seem to want (start some threads so they will run on multiple cores) you probably want to let the scheduler do the scheduling.

Setting processor affinity is basically for cases where you know enough about scheduling of your threads that you can do a better job of scheduling than a general purpose scheduler can. At least from what I've seen, roughly 75% of the time that people set affinity, it's basically a mistake, and they end up slowing their code down. Another 24% they do no harm, but also do no real good. And, perhaps as much as 1% of the time, they actually accomplish something useful.

Rest assured that people who write schedulers are generally aware that if you spin up a dozen threads, it wasn't with the intent that they all run on a single core. The simplest (and probably most common) case is for it to simply schedule threads on all available cores. When it doesn't, it's usually because the user has (at least indirectly) configured the system not to (e.g., part of power management on a laptop may be that when it's running on battery, it limits the number of cores in use, at least under some circumstances).